# using a table adapter to insert data into a SQL Server database from a string array in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, arrays, tableadapter

I have the following method:

```
public void LottoTest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dictionary<int, int> numbers = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            Random generator = new Random();
            while (numbers.Count < 6)
            {
                numbers[generator.Next(1, 49)] = 1;
            }

            string[] lotto = numbers.Keys.OrderBy(n => n).Select(s => s.ToString()).ToArray();

            foreach (String _str in lotto)
            {
                Response.Write(_str);
                Response.Write(",");
            }
        }
```

I would like to insert the contents of the `lotto` array into a SQL Server 2008 database. The problem is i dont know how to do this at all. I have searched various ways insert database using C# and i find using a table adapter to create stored procedures is the best.

How do i utilise this table adapter to insert the data from the `lotto` array?

Comment: Do you have a table setup in your database?

Comment: Yes, LOTTOID, NUMBERS, DRAWDATE

Comment: database is created. table adapter is setup, just dont know the syntax to grab the array contents to then make the table adapter write the data into the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start reading here:

[MSDN Table Adapters Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zt3ycf2.aspx)

That being said - here is how I would do it (depending how the numbers were passed in to me).

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Lotto
    {
        public void InsertLottoNumbers(int[] lottonumbers)
        {
            var connectionstring = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;";

            using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))  // Create connection with automatic disposal
            {
                con.Open();
                using (var tran = con.BeginTransaction())  // Open a transaction
                {
                    // Create command with parameters  (DO NOT PUT VALUES IN LINE!!!!!)
                    string sql =
                        "insert into MyTable(val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6) values (@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4,@val5,@val6)";
                    var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("val1", lottonumbers[0]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("val2", lottonumbers[1]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("val3", lottonumbers[2]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("val4", lottonumbers[3]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("val5", lottonumbers[4]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("val6", lottonumbers[5]);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Insert Record

                    tran.Commit();  // commit transaction
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks.. this is useful but isnt it bad practice to have SQL insert statements inside the body of the code?

Comment: I was also going to just put the comma delimited list of lotto numbers into one column in the database. I see you actually broke down the values. Hmmmm

Comment: In terms of bad practice - it depends on what you are building.  For a production application I put this kind of code into a data layer or use an ORM tool.  For small applications that don't need an abstraction between the UI / Business Logic / and Data layers this would be fine.

Comment: I see, its just a dummy application to prove a few things, and test out logic with numbers and probability etc... thanks